# Python setup.py build cannot find standard include for gcc

Tags: python, gcc, include-path, setup.py

I'm trying to build some openmp based python software (pynbody). I can do this on my mac laptop, but when I try on my mac desktop the gcc call can't find all the sys includes (like _int8.h). I've tried everything from

```
python setup.py config -I/...:/...:/...
```

to

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/...:/...:/...
```

But I ALWAYS get `(fatal error: sys/_types/_int8_t.h: No such file or directory)`.

```
gcc: pynbody/sph/smooth.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/include/stdint.h:9:0,
                 from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/inttypes.h:255,
                 from /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7/pyport.h:9,
                 from /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from pynbody/sph/kd.h:4,
                 from pynbody/sph/smooth.h:5,
                 from pynbody/sph/smooth.cpp:6:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/include-fixed/stdint.h:27:32: fatal error: sys/_types/_int8_t.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/include/stdint.h:9:0,
                 from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/inttypes.h:255,
                 from /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7/pyport.h:9,
                 from /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from pynbody/sph/kd.h:4,
                 from pynbody/sph/smooth.h:5,
                 from pynbody/sph/smooth.cpp:6:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/include-fixed/stdint.h:27:32: fatal error: sys/_types/_int8_t.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -UDEBUG -I/usr/local/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -c pynbody/sph/smooth.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pynbody/sph/smooth.o -ftree-vectorize -fno-omit-frame-pointer -funroll-loops -fprefetch-loop-arrays -fstrict-aliasing -g -DKDT_THREADING" failed with exit status 1
```

I've run out of ideas... Anyone know how to get python to look at a set of user-specified include directories?

Comment: Run `xcode-select --install` - it seems you are missing some tools.

Comment: I tried that... the command line tools are installed, and the includes are there. But python isn't finiding them... It's looking in one place only. -- /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/include

Answer (score 0):

Use Finder to see if you even have the header. If you do, you will need to add the location of the sys directory to your include path.

Comment: I have the files... in multiple places: /usr/local/include, /usr/include ... and under some /Application and /Library dirs... How do I update the include path? python configure -I/... didn't work... And export C_INCLUDE_PATH didn't either.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust these directories in setup.cfg.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your answer to include more details, an example may help or pointing out the exact sections of setup.cfg that require adjustment could also make your answer more helpful.